# Wheel scroll event override to increment one element up/down

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm doing a project in Windows Presentation Foundation.
I have a `ListBox` in which every `element` is the same `height`.

**What I want to achieve is:**

- When I `Mouse Wheel Scroll` up or down I want `ListBox` to increment/decrement view by always one element.

**What I have right now:**

- When I `Mouse Wheel Scroll` up or down it always increments/decrements a couple of (depending on screen height) elements.

Are there any easy solutions for this ?

Thanks

Comment: you must be able to disable scroll yet capture the scroll event and then use `JQuery` or alike, to then scroll your items to a predefined height which you have stated. Don't ask me for examples though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply fast hack for this (it means you can do this in a nicer way, maybe with an attached behaviour)

```
private void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  var lb = sender as ListBox;
  if (lb != null) {
    // get or store scrollviewer
    if (lb.Tag == null) {
      lb.Tag = GetDescendantByType(lb, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
    }
    var lbScrollViewer = lb.Tag as ScrollViewer;
    if (lbScrollViewer != null) {
      if (e.Delta < 0) {
        lbScrollViewer.LineDown();
      } else {
        lbScrollViewer.LineUp();
      }
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

GetDescendantByType method

```
public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
{
  if (element == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (element.GetType() == type) {
    return element;
  }
  Visual foundElement = null;
  if (element is FrameworkElement) {
    (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++) {
    Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
    foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
    if (foundElement != null) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return foundElement;
}
```

usage

```
<ListBox PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel" />
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly what I did ! Except that I've used an `ItemsControl` instead of a `ListBox` wrapped in a `ScrollView` with Attached Behaviour.
Thanks!